# F# match question

Tags: f#

this is what i have so far:

```
type u = {str : string} //some type that has some property str (for simplicity, only one)
type du=
   | A of u
   | B of u // some discriminated union that carries u with it
```

then, somewhere i have a sequence of du that i am doing distinctBy and the property to do distinct is str. 
best i could come up with is this:

```
Seq.distinctBy (fun d -> match d with (A u|B u) -> u.str)
```

the code works, but i don't like having to match on a and b of the discriminated union and would like to replace the match with something.

question is, what? :)

EDIT:

in my case, a and b of the discriminated union will always carry same type u with them, one solution is to get rid of du and add it's string form to type u and simplify this whole mess, but i would like to keep it this way for now because i was going to do matches and such on the a and b...

Comment: I believe discriminated union cases must be upper case - not sure why this is though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about doing the match one time as a property of du?

```
type u = {str : string}

type du =
    | A of u
    | B of u with
    member this.U =
        match this with
        (A u | B u) -> u

[A {str="hello"}; B {str="world"}; A {str="world"}]
|> Seq.distinctBy (fun x -> x.U.str)

//val it : seq<du> = seq [A {str = "hello";}; B {str = "world";}]
```

However, I have a couple ideas which may model the relationship between u and du better while satisfying your "EDIT" concerns. One way is simply using tuples:

```
type u = {str : string}

type du =
    | A
    | B

//focus on type u
[A, {str="hello"}; B, {str="world"}; A, {str="world"}]
|> Seq.distinctBy (fun (_,x) -> x.str)
//val it : seq<du * u> = seq [(A, {str = "hello";}); (B, {str = "world";})]

//focus on type du
let x = A, {str="hello"}
match x with
| A,_ -> "A"
| B,_ -> "B"
//val it : string = "A"
```

Another way is to switch it around and add du to u:

```
type du =
    | A
    | B

type u = { case : du; str : string}

//focus on type u
[{case=A; str="hello"}; {case=B; str="world"}; {case=A; str="world"}]
|> Seq.distinctBy (fun x -> x.str)
//val it : seq<u> = seq [{case = A;
//                        str = "hello";}; {case = B;
//                                          str = "world";}]

//focus on type du
let x = {case=A; str="hello"}
match x with
| {case=A} -> "A"
| {case=B} -> "B"
//val it : string = "A"
```

Comment: i think as far as my question, your first answer would fit the best, i still have to think a bit about my model, but the idea of having a property is pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

You really can't simplify it as much as you describe but you can simplify it. *Thanks @Tomas Petricek*

```
[ A { str = "A" }; B { str = "B" }; B { str = "B" } ] 
|> Seq.distinctBy (fun (A u | B u) -> u.str) 
|> Seq.toArray;;
```

**Output**

```
[| A {str = "A";}; B {str = "B";} |]
```

Comment: You can make it by 3 characters shorter by using `fun (A u | B u)` instead of `function A u | B u` :-)

Comment: @Tomas - Oh F# when will you stop surprising me?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit new to F# but hopefully this will help.  It seems to me that Active Patterns might make your life easier in trying to cut down what you need to type in your pattern matching.  Instead of using A a | B b you can use the active pattern AorB in it's place.

```
type u = { str : string }

type du = 
    | A of u
    | B of u

let (|AorB|) (v:du) =
    match v with
        | A a -> a
        | B b -> b

[A { str = "A" }; B { str = "B"}; A { str = "A"}]
    |> Seq.distinctBy (fun d -> 
                    match d with 
                        | AorB s -> s)
    |> Seq.iter (fun i -> match i with AorB c -> printfn "%s" c.str)
```

With Stephen's addition the final expression can be written thusly.

```
[A { str = "A" }; B { str = "B"}; A { str = "A"}]
|> Seq.distinctBy (|AorB|)
|> Seq.iter (fun i -> match i with AorB c -> printfn "%s" c.str)
```

Comment: Hey @LLama - it gets even better, when using an active pattern like this, you can do `... |> Seq.distinctBy (|AorB|) ...`

Comment: You sir officially blew my mind with that one, wow!  Thanx for the tip!

Comment: Hehe - yes, who knew a programming language could be full of such true delights! I studied math as an undergraduate, and work now as a software engineer: but it wasn't until I discovered F# that I experience the same level of amazement in CS as I do in math (precisely because as a language, F# lessens the impedance mismatch between mathematical thought and expression)!